# Datalist disappear when inputing a white space

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I'm trying to create an input bar that suggest tags.
We can enter differents tags by separating them with a white space.
I'm using a datalist to suggest tags, and I developped it to only match the characters after the last white space (e.g.: if I input "stack overfl", the datalist will suggest tags that match with "overfl").

It works well with the first tag, but at the moment I enter a white space, the datalist will update itself correctly but won't show. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Here is my code for updating the datalist.

```
$("#tagInput").keypress(function (e) {
    //Get value of input element
    var input = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    //Remove every characters before the last white space
    while(input.indexOf(' ') > 0) {
        input = input.substr(input.indexOf(' ') + 1);
    }
    console.log(input);
    //suggest = datalist
    var suggest = $("#suggest");
    //Removing every elements from datalist
    suggest.empty();
    //Get every matching tags
    var suggestion = getSuggestion(input);
    for(let i = 0; i < suggestion.length; i++)
        suggest.append("<option value='"+suggestion[i]+"'></option>");
})

function getSuggestion(input){
    var result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < window.tagList.length; i++){
        if(window.tagList[i].toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase(), 0))
            result.push(window.tagList[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```